# Symfony 2.1 - Install a bundle without Composer

Tags: symfony-2.1, composer-php

Still many bundles don't have `composer.json` included, so what is the proper way to install them without composer? Should we still use `deps` file ? How to manage autoloader in that case ? Please don't tell me to fork each project and add the `composer.json`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the composer.json for the bundle inline inside yours using a [package repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2). That said once you did that the best is to also fork the bundle and send a pull request with the composer.json. Most bundles are already available, and if the fringe ones get pull requests as soon as someone needs them the situation will improve pretty quickly.

Comment: Not worth an own answer, but: You should not mix `deps` and Composer. And forking and contributing the missing `composer.json` is (at minimum) quite nice :)